# Application Loader not load Build

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, application-loader

To be more precise. Load build successfully but not showed in iTunes Connect, this behavior i see after last update xCode 6.3. For CI this step pass (upload build) successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i resolve my trouble. Just upload build manually from xCode archiver.